# How to connect to Teradata from pyspark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, teradata, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to connect to Teradata and DB2 from Pyspark.

I am using the below jars :

*tdgssconfig-15.10.00.14.jar*
*teradata-connector-1.4.1.jar*
*terajdbc4-15.10.00.14.jar*
&
*db2jcc4.jar*

Connection string:

```
df1 = sqlContext.load(source="jdbc", driver="com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver", url=db_url,user="db_user",TMODE="TERA",password="db_pwd",dbtable="U114473.EMPLOYEE")

df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(url='jdbc:db2://10.123.321.9:50000/DB599641',user='******',password='*****',driver='com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver', dbtable='DSN1.EMPLOYEE')
```

Both gives me Driver not found error.

Can we use JDBC drivers for pyspark?

Comment: when you say "you are using the below jars", are you meaning you're starting your your session using something like `pyspark --jars /path/to/jar1,/path/to/jar2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Like James Tobin said, use the pyspark2 --jars /jarpath option when you start your pyspark sessioni or when you submit your py to spark